# Why are magic items rarely on the Auction House?

Tags: diablo-iii

Most items on auction house are either rare or some socketed magic item.

Why do only these types of items appear to be put up for auction?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Probably because the answer is obvious; crappy blue items are common and not typically useful.

Comment: Is obvious answers off topic?

Comment: @JimThio Obvious questions are not off-topic, but people may consider them not useful which ends up in downvotes.

Comment: Question should be close as there is no longer an auction house for diablo 3.

Comment: Question should not be closed. See [this answer](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8451/50582) to your own meta question about D3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like there are usually a bunch of magic items there as well. A good option if you want to search for cheap equipment is to enter maximum buyout price when searching. At lower prices, the proportion of blue items tends to be higher.

Answer (score 1):

Because they are worth something? Compared to the magic items?

Gray, White and Blue items pretty much never sell, so people put better equip than that in the AH.

Comment: I'd rather buy blue item at 2k gold than a yellow item at 20k gold.

Comment: Well, players rather want to scavenge 2k items to make room in their AH for the item of 20k gold. THATS CAPITALISM.

Comment: @JimThio - I've sometimes put magic items with <mainstat>/vit on AH for 2x vendor cost, and they don't sell :/ Granted these were for end Normal to early NM, not ilvl 60 ... but crappier rares sell faster.